# Wordpress Dashboard Incoming Links Error

Tags: rss, dashboard

Hy all!

I have a problem with the Wordpress Dashboard - the Incoming Links are not working. I only get "A feed could not be found at http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch_feeds?hl=de&scoring=d&ie=utf-8&num=10&output=rss&partner=wordpress&q=link:http://www.markus-schober.at/".
I have tried a few solution but nothing works for me. 
Here is the link, that I have added: "http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch_feeds?hl=de&scoring=d&ie=utf-8&num=10&output=rss&partner=wordpress&q=link:http://www.markus-schober.at/"

Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Click configure and copy the URL (in your case, it sounds like it
   is:
   http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch_feeds?hl=de&scoring=d&ie=utf-8&num=10&output=rss&partner=wordpress&q=link:http://www.markus-schober.at/)
2. Paste the URL into your browser, and you'll notice that it redirects
   you to
   https://www.google.com/search?hl=de&ie=utf-8&q=link:http://www.markus-schober.at/%22&tbm=blg&tbs=sbd:1&output=rss
3. Copy the URL that it redirects to in Step 2, and paste that into the
   textbox that appears when you click Configure.
4. Save your changes, and the widget should populate correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be linked to the host provider, Host Gator.  None of my other Wordpress blogs are having this issue but ALL of the ones hosted at Hostgator are.

Is your blog also hosted at Host Gator?

I'm opening a ticket with them now - sounds like a server issue.  I'll report back on their answer.

Comment: No, it isn't hosted at Host Gator. But i think, you are allright. Maybe the Hoster allows no external URL. I will write a ticket to my hoster and post the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Markus:

Here's what Hostgator said:

I'm very sorry you've had problems with your feeds. This issue was caused by the feeds hitting a mod_security rule and therefore getting blocked. I have whitelisted all 5 of the domains you mentioned against that mod security rule so that this won't happen again. If you have any other domains that had this same problem, please let us know and we'll be happy to fix those as well.

Unfortunately, that didn't resolve the issue.  However, I found this on the web and I've sent that to HostGator to ask them to try what I found at this thread (the php.ini instructions):

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/rss-error-the-feed-could-not-be-found

I'll let you know if doing this fixes the problem.

Comment: Please edit your answers or comment instead of creating multiple ones. You might need to register so that works properly.

Answer (score -2):

The Solution is simple:
Click “Configure” on the right top of your link:
Enter the RSS feed URL here:
https://www.google.com/search?ie=utf-8&q=link:http://media-islam.or.id/&tbm=blg&tbs=sbd:1&output=rss

Change media-islam.or.id with your domain name.
Read more at:
http://media-islam.or.id/2012/09/08/solusi-masalah-wordpress-incoming-links-error/